# How do I install Microsoft FlexGrid Control 6.0 on a computer without VS 6.0?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, msflexgrid

My VB.NET application uses Microsoft Flex Grid Control 6.0. This is a legacy application which has been ported from VB6 with the Visual Studio conversion wizard. Although I can compile the assembly, I get a COMException because some class is not registered. I've found out that this class is the Microsoft Flex Grid Control 6.0.

Where can I find the control and how can I register it on machines so that the application will run?

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: You haven't said how you are deploying your ported-to-.Net application.  A proper installer should be taking care of putting a copy of the OCX on target machines and registering it, or you may be able to "isolate" it using reg-free COM.  Are you trying to use ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Microsoft FlexGrid Control" MSFlxGrd.ocx [shipped with Visual Basic 6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194784). It is an ActiveX control. The easiest way to get the control is to install Visual Basic 6. If you have an MSDN subscription, VB6 is available as a free download. But I am surprised you can compile your application if the control is not already installed on your development machine.

Once you have found the control, you need to register it on the machines where you need your program to run. The easiest way is just to create a deployment project. If you want to do it manually, use [regsvr32](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true) from the command line.