# Vba activate grid control as additional control

Tags: vba, user-interface, gridcontrol, catia

I want to add control to user GUI that would represent excel like table but I cannot find additional control that would do that. Control like that would be used for easier data entry.

I believe that VBA has control like that and I am missing something obvious.

Does anyone know where to activate control like that?

[image: Something like this control]

Comment: In Access, it's called datasheet view. Create an empty wrapper form (the outside frame), then add an inside continuous form and set its view to datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VB6 installed then, this should work:

[Microsoft Flex Grid Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887260/how-do-i-install-microsoft-flexgrid-control-6-0-on-a-computer-without-vs-6-0)

However, if you do not have (vb6) then, another option is to create one yourself by dynamically adding controls to your UserForm (such as a textbox) and then tracking those object. It would take some work, but it would be an option.

Comment: If you d go down the route of adding text controls to create your own grid, the trick is to name them all Textxy where x and y are digits that identify the row and column they're in. It makes it much easier to manage what goes where, as you can use loops to fill and read the data

Comment: I use `Name="Cell(" & inti & "," & "intj" & ")"` to identify them as you will not need to worry about digit sizes and parsing.

Comment: Thank you, I have created my own grid using your guideline.